# Cual es la diferencia entre zafar y escapar?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

Yo le pregunté a chatgpt cual es la diferencia y me respondió que:

> En resumen, "zafar" se refiere a liberarse de una situación difícil o
> a desatascar algo, mientras que "escapar" se refiere a salir
> rápidamente de una situación o lugar para evitar algo o alguien.

No entendí la diferencia en esta repuesta. Los dos se refieren a escapar situaciones. Creo que los dos son sinónimos, pero queria la opinión de un hispanohablante humano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Son verbos que tienen connotaciones similares. Pero *escapar* suele usarse para referirse literalmente a la acción de salir físicamente de un lugar, mientras que *zafar* debe entenderse como 'evitar' caer en una situación no deseada, pudiendo esto último deberse a la propia voluntad o no. Algunos ejemplos:

- Me estaba persiguiendo la policía pero logré *escapar* (= salí de la línea de visión de todos los patrulleros). *Zafé* de que me atrapasen.
- Ayer *escapé* de la cárcel (= salí del perímetro que delimita el área de las instalaciones carcelarias). *Zafé* de tener que pasar el resto de mi vida en prisión.
- Quise cachetear a un mosquito pero se me *escapó* (de mi mano). *Zafó* de que lo matara.
- El otro día vino mi suegra a mi casa pero me *pegué una escapada* (= me fui de viaje por un tiempo corto). *Zafé* de tener que soportarla.
- En el examen de ayer copié. Aunque se me *escapó el detalle* de haber dejado el machete arriba de la mesa, el profesor no se dio cuenta y *zafé* de que me sancionaran.

OBS.: Con elementos mecánicos (tornillos, tuercas, arandelas, bisagras, etc.) se prefiere *zafar*, sobre todo cuando se presupone que no deberían hacerlo—es decir, ocasionan el daño o mal funcionamiento en algún mecanismo:

- Se *zafó* el tornillo del agujero de la pared, lo que provocó el incidente de la caída del estante.

También está la expresión *se le zafó un tornillo*, que, por analogía, se dice de alguien cuando pierde la cordura.

Answer (score 1):

Como tu muy bien comentas "**zafar**" y "**escapar**" pueden funcionar como símil y de hecho funcionan bastante bien cuando se refiere al sentido de "**huir**". Sin embargo, existen algunos matices que podríamos tener en cuenta. La palabra "**zafar**" (zafarse), también puede significar soltarse, salirse, liberarse de algo y en mi opinión posee además un punto de ingenio o astucia que no tiene la palabra "**escapar**" (escaparse), a no ser que se especifique, ya que "escapar" en esta comparativa, básicamente significa "*estar fuera o salir del alcance de*".

Ejemplos;

- Por ejemplo se utiliza la palabra "**zafar**" (*zafarse*) cuando queremos poner de relieve que hemos evitado un peligro utilizando cierto ingenio. Imaginemos que nos persiguen y para evitar que nos detengan, nos escondemos detrás de unos arbustos o nos disfrazamos para no ser reconocidos. En este caso podemos utilizar la palabra "escapar" pero si deseamos poner de relieve cierta argucia por nuestra parte en la manera de escaparnos, diremos pues, "que nos estamos "**zafando** de nuestros perseguidores", con el fin de eludirlos o evitarlos.
- Otro ejemplo. Si decimos "*zafarnos de un embotellamiento*" significa que hemos encontrado alguna artimaña, una excusa, un camino diferente o un artificio, que nos ha permitido "**evitar**" el tráfico.
- Si alguien al que conocemos y al que consideramos una persona a la que hay que "**evitar**", pues es una persona muy molesta o desagradable. Si este individuo nos para y nos quiere invitar a un café para hablar con nosotros de algo, "nosotros podemos "**zafarnos**" poniendo una excusa, por ejemplo, "*lo siento, pero voy de camino al hospital... y no puedo, en otra ocasión será*". Así, usted se ha "**zafado**", es decir, ha **evitado** a esa persona poniendo una excusa y ha podido "**escaparse**", esto es, "*salir del alcance de*" esa persona.
- De igual manera podemos utilizar las dos palabras en una misma frase, "Me **zafe** de mis ligaduras y después **escape**", en este caso tiene el sentido de liberarse de algo para posteriormente "huir" o "escapar". *Primero "me zafo" evito o me libero de las ligaduras que tenía puestas y después escapo* (salgo del alcance de los malhechores).

En resumen básicamente "**zafar**" llevaría implícito el sentido o la connotación de "*evitar o liberarse de algo o alguien con excusas, ingenio, astucia o artificios*", mientras que "**escapar**" sería fundamentalmente "*salir del alcance de algo o de alguien*".

Comment: Gracias, aprecio el resumen para mi baraja Anki.